# Creating R Bookdown book with duplicate sub-section names - Works but ToC always links to first instance

Tags: r, bookdown

I have created several books using bookdown and each chapter has an "Exercises" sub-section. Previously, bookdown would append a '-1' or '-2' to the duplicate section labels, but the resulting output would only show the "Exercises" and the link would work correctly.

Now, the webpage ToC links all the repeated labels to the first chapter with an "Exercises" sub-section.

I know there is is a

```
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
```

that will allow duplicate chunk names, but I can't find a way to allow for duplicate section labels.

I know I can fix this by just renaming each chapter exercises to something unique, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

A solution I found was to modify the label as follows

```
## Exercises {#A-Unique-Label-Exercises}
```

This allows me to have the reader just see Exercises, but I add a unique label that can be as long and annoying as I want.

---

An addendum from the **bookdown** developer:

> This is a bug introduced in the last version of **bookdown**, which [has been fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/909#issuecomment-662525718) in the current development version. You may try:
>
> ```r
> remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
> ```

Comment: Haha, could be me ... you search for hours and 5 minutes after posting on SO your find the perfect answer on your own. But yes, this is the standard way to deal with this problem. Adding your own labels makes it also easier to link/refer in your text to chapters/sections.